# Cómo puedo trabajar con dos referencias de Database en Firebase sin que una de las dos me arroje error

Tags: java, android, firebase

Lo que pasa es que estoy intentando discriminar dos tipos de usuarios, uno es un usuario Normal y el otro es usuario Empresa. En mi base de datos tengo una lista de usuarios Normal que están en "users" y otra lista de usuarios Empresa que están en "users empresas". Lo que estoy haciendo es buscar su Uid en las referencias de abajo y viendo si existe en una referencia y en la otra no, de esta manera, poder conocer qué tipo de usuario es (si es Normal o Empresa).

El problema que tengo es que cuando ingresa a buscar el Uid a la referencia donde el Uid no existe, este me arroja error y me dice que no puedo trabajar con un null object reference y es obvio porque en una de las dos referencias este dato no existirá y así sabre que tipo de usuario es, pero el error ocurre en .child(user_id) y no sé cómo puedo dejar de trabajar con la referencia que es nula antes de que me arroje el error y me cierre la aplicación...

```
Database.child("users").child(user_id).addValueEventListener(
                                                    new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                                                                UidUser = usuario.getUid();  
                                                        }
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                        }
                                                    });

Database.child("users empresas").child(user_id).addValueEventListener(
                                                new ValueEventListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
                                                            Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                                                            UidUserEmp = usuario.getUid();

                                                    }
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                    }
                                                });
```

Hacer algo como lo siguiente pero de una manera correcta

```
if(Database.child("users empresas").child(user_id) != null){
//Hacer algo
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias por todo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando obtienes tu `DataSnapshot` puedes usar el método [`exist()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html?authuser=0#exists()) para verificar si el snapshot existe:

```
Database.child("users").child(user_id).addValueEventListener(
                                                    new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) return; // O lo que quieras hacer para no trabajar con él
                                                                Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                                                                UidUser = usuario.getUid();  
                                                        }
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                        }
                                                    });
```

Aunque yo te recomiendo mejor no hacer dos bases de usuarios separadas sino un solo tipo, entonces puedes darle un `tipo` al usuario y allí le ponés si es usuario Normal o Empresa. De esa manera usas una sola referencia.

Comment: Eso hice amigo, muchas gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: A la orden Matías... Ya sabés.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder esquivarla podes hacer lo siguiente

Aqui declaro el auth de firebase con el que se obtendria el user_id

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid();  //aca obtienes tu user id
```

Esto es lo que estas haciendo para poner el user_id en tu child, pero si compruebas que eso sea null no te va a funcionar, por que para obtener el userID primero tenes que obtener el currentUser, y este es el que te da null y de esa forma no llegas nunca al uid

Entonces para comprobar solamente haces esto

```
if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
//tu codigo...
}
```

Espero te sirva

saludos